# Calling ebay trading api from within Django class based view does not work, but works in console

Tags: python, django, api, class, trading

I am currently working on a listing module for ebay. The ebay trading API is done and works fine when I test run it in the console. However when I try to call the same function within a class based view, I get an 500 server error.

This is the class:

```
class ListSimpleProduct(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin): 

    queryset = SimpleProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SimpleProductSerializer
    def post(self, request, pk): 
        product = SimpleProduct.objects.get(sku=pk)
        serializer = SimpleProductSerializer(product, many=False)
        data = serializer.data
        item = buildItem(data)
        addItemCheck(item)
        return Response({
            'data': "Item listed on ebay"
        })
```

And this is the addItemCheck function in the ebay API:

```
def addItemCheck(item):

    (opts, args) = init_options()
    try:
        print("Line 100")
        api = Trading(debug=opts.debug, config_file=opts.yaml, appid=opts.appid, domain=opts.domain,
                      certid=opts.certid, devid=opts.devid, warnings=True, timeout=20, siteid=opts.siteid)
        print("Line 103")
        response = api.execute('VerifyAddItem', item)
        print("Line 105")
        info = response.dict()
        print("Line 107")
        return info
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
        print(e.response.dict())
```

It works until line 100, so the function gets called. The mistake must be in api variable. The data I give to the function is the exact same I put in from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it out finally. The path to the yaml file was hardcoded so it could find it when starting over terminal but not with a running server. If anybody ever has the same error, go under "Django best practices" to find the solution.